# youtube videos and photos in blog post in django

Tags: python, django, youtube-api

I want to integrate youtube videos and photos in my django blog posts. The youtube data API and youtube analyticis API documentation is very confusing. Can someone point me in the right direction. How should I go on to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

The general format of the iframe you need to embed is this:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="' + {{ w }} + '" height="' + {{ h }} + '" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + {{ youtubelink }} + '" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Insert that into your template wherever it is you need the video on your page.  You need to pass into the template the variables `w`, `h`, and `youtubelink` (which will be of the form `h5EofwRzit0`, and can be lifted right out of the url for that video).  Of course, any or all of these could be hard-coded rather than requiring variables to be passed if you prefer.  That should be all you need to display a video.

Answer (score 0):

here video_id is the id in the

```
youtube url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id <- video_id is this one.
```

for thumbnail images use this url

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{video_id}}/0.jpg
```

0.jpg is always hd thumbnail image .. 1.jpg, 2.jpg 3.jpg is for thumbnail 1,2,3

use the following JS for getting info like title/desc/comments etc..

```
   function getYouTubeInfo(video_id) {
            $.ajax({
                    url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+video_id+"?v=2&alt=json",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data) { 
                      parseresults(data,video_id); 
                    }
            });
    }

    function parseresults(data,video_id) {
            var title = data.entry.title.$t;
            var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
            var viewcount = data.entry.yt$statistics.viewCount;
            var author = data.entry.author[0].name.$t;
            //var pubdate=data.entry.published.$t;

            var pubdate = new Date( data.entry[ "published" ].$t.substr( 0, 4 ), data.entry[ "published" ].$t.substr( 5, 2 ) - 1, data.entry[ "published" ].$t.substr( 8, 2 ) ).toLocaleDateString( )

          //  document.getElementById('jsmessage').innerHTML+=video_id;
            var title_id='#title'+video_id;
            var description_id='#description'+video_id;
            var extrainfo_id='#extrainfo'+video_id;
            var pubdate_id='#pubdate'+video_id;

            $(title_id).html(title);
            $(pubdate_id).html('<b>Added on: </b>'+pubdate)
            $(description_id).html('<b>Description</b>: ' + description);
            $(extrainfo_id).html('<b>Author</b>: ' + author + '<br/><b>Views</b>: ' + viewcount);
         //   getComments(data.entry.gd$comments.gd$feedLink.href + '&max-results=50&alt=json', 1);
    }




    function getComments(commentsURL, startIndex) {
            $.ajax({
                    url: commentsURL + '&start-index=' + startIndex,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(key, val) {
                            $('#comments').append('<br/>Author: ' + val.author[0].name.$t + ', Comment: ' + val.content.$t);
                    });
                    if ($(data.feed.entry).size() == 50) { getComments(commentsURL, startIndex + 50); }
                    }
            });
    }
```